# The speed of information retrieved from the database

Tags: angular, database, asp.net-web-api, treeview, webapi

I list the data I pulled from the database in treeview. But I have one question. I have a city, county and neighborhood table. I write the districts of the selected province and the neighborhoods of the selected district on the table. There is no problem in printing one by one, but when we select a lot of data (all), this process takes about 17 minutes to run on the network. When I remove my hand from the All key, new data is constantly coming due to the request to the wep api.

What comes to my mind as a solution to this is;

Stopping the network when we stop selecting the All button.
Making the user wait using the site by adding a 20-minute delay. (it doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: 17 minutes is way too much. How is the user interacting with your controls? Can you fetch all of the counties first, then when the user selects a county fetch cities for that particular selection, and after you know the city too, fetch the neighborhoods of the selected city?

Comment: Instead, I easily found a solution by writing a function that will cancel all pending queries when the button is pulled. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private ngUnsubscribeNeighborhood = new Subject();`
using the structure. I made a pipe assignment to the place where we subscribe. I set Pipe to takeUntil and assign it to ngUnsubscribeNeighborhood. Then I clicked a button. `ngUnsubscribeMahalle.next();` I solved the problem by doing

Answer (score 1):

try googling virtual scrolling it may help. Since the ngFor takes time to render the large data using virtual scrolling can help reducing the render time.